# How to automate select controls in a grid (clicks and holds) using selenium (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code is:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void ActionClickAndHold()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://jqueryui.com/selectable/");

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("selectable")).Click();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstItems = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='selectable']/li[1]"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.ClickAndHold(lstItems[1])
                .ClickAndHold(lstItems[3])
                .Click()
                .Perform();
        driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    }
```

It does not work. It does not click and holds in a grid. Where do I know my mistake?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, can you see where it's getting stuck?

I'm not sure why you're clicking the "selectable" element to begin with, and why you're switching to the frame **after** you find and click it...

Comment: Do you know selenium with C#?

Comment: Yes, but it would be helpful to know where your program is failing, to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are going to wrong element, try as below :-

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://jqueryui.com/selectable/");

var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.ClassName("demo-frame")));

ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstItems = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.CssSelector("#selectable li")));

builder.ClickAndHold(lstItems[1])
                .ClickAndHold(lstItems[3])
                .Click()
                .Perform();
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Thank you so much.
Can you explain the command line? I do not understand.

Comment: @D.ÝNguyện everything is the same as you have already done, the only difference is with the locator, you are going to use `xpath` which locate only single `li` element while you should need all `li` elements, and new thing I implemented [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) which will wait for element until all elemnts visible on the dom...:)

Comment: @D.ÝNguyện [`FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt.htm) is use to wait for frame present then switch to it..:)